# Webpack doesn't compile my javascript file due to Regexp

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony4, webpack-encore

I'm working on a Symfony 4 project using Webpack Encore. Using `yarn encore dev`, I get this error :

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                 11:45:38

These dependencies were not found:

* core-js/modules/es.regexp.exec in ./assets/js/poteauxskip.js
* core-js/modules/es.string.match in ./assets/js/poteauxskip.js

To install them, you can run: npm install --save core-js/modules/es.regexp.exec core-js/modules/es.string.match
```

And the Regexp expression doesn't work. I tried to install as they say, but it's the beginning of all sorts of problems. But mainly, it doesn't solves the main problem, which is: why doesn't this work? I see no reason to import anything in my javascript file to use Regexp, I found no mention of this in my whole research for a solution.

poteauxskip.js file :

```
const $ = require('jquery');

$(".tableau").addClass("d-none");

$(".serie").change(function(){
    updateTableaux();
});

function updateTableaux() {
    var serie1 = $("select#serie1").val() == '?' ? '[0-9A-F]' : $("select#serie1").val();
    var serie2 = $("select#serie2").val() == '?' ? '[0-9A-F]' : $("select#serie2").val();
    var serie3 = $("select#serie3").val() == '?' ? '[0-9A-F]' : $("select#serie3").val();
    var serie4 = $("select#serie4").val() == '?' ? '[0-9A-F]' : $("select#serie4").val();
    var serie5 = $("select#serie5").val() == '?' ? '[0-9A-F]' : $("select#serie5").val();
    var serie6 = $("select#serie6").val() == '?' ? '[0-9A-F]' : $("select#serie6").val();

    var regex = new Regexp("/" + serie1 + serie2 + serie3 + serie4 + serie5 + serie6 + "$/");

    alert("12".match(regex));
}
```

The alert works if I test it for something else. The other variables also work if I use it without any Regexp. Actually, the `new Regexp()` or the `string.match()` are enough to get a compilation error.

package.json :

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.27.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "popper": "^1.0.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.6.0"
  },
  "name": "hyperbolic-world",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "Pour favoriser l'immersion dans un espace hyperbolique.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Julien Busset",
  "license": "CC-BY-4.0",
  "directories": {
    "test": "tests"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js :

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Add 1 entry for each "page" of your app
     * (including one that's included on every page - e.g. "app")
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if you JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .addEntry('poteauxskip', './assets/js/poteauxskip.js')
    //.addEntry('page1', './assets/js/page1.js')
    //.addEntry('page2', './assets/js/page2.js')

    // When enabled, Webpack "splits" your files into smaller pieces for greater optimization.
    .splitEntryChunks()

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    /*
     * FEATURE CONFIG
     *
     * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
     * list of features, see:
     * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
     */
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // enables @babel/preset-env polyfills
    .configureBabel(() => {}, {
        useBuiltIns: 'usage',
        corejs: 3
    })

    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    .enableSassLoader()
    //.addStyleEntry('global', './assets/scss/global.scss')

    // uncomment if you use TypeScript
    //.enableTypeScriptLoader()

    // uncomment to get integrity="..." attributes on your script & link tags
    // requires WebpackEncoreBundle 1.4 or higher
    //.enableIntegrityHashes()

    // uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
    //.autoProvidejQuery()

    // uncomment if you use API Platform Admin (composer req api-admin)
    //.enableReactPreset()
    //.addEntry('admin', './assets/js/admin.js')
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Comment: I just tried `yarn add core-js`, and I do not have the compilation problem anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem solved by adding core-js with `yarn add core-js --dev`.

Comment: But I still have another problem, which is the `new Regexp` doesn't work and blocks the further instructions. However, a `string.match(any_regex)` works, so it's better.